# how to make a date picker in Android?

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator

Could we have a DATE picker in Android that is not calling the popup dialog?

Why is useSpinner deprecated in 5.4.0?

I made a test like this, and it resulted in a strange black field and I don't see any dropdown.

```
var androidDatePicker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
        type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
        height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
        width:Ti.UI.FILL,
        minDate:moment().add(10,"minutes").toDate(),
        maxDate:moment().add(2,"years").toDate(),
        value:moment().toDate()
    });
    $.main.add(androidDatePicker);
```

Comment: As per Material Design guidelines, it is not suggested to use spinner type date picker. Instead the standard dialog type is more preferred nowadays using Ti.UI.Picker. showDatePickerDialog()

Answer (score 0):

For some purposes it works. I know other developers whose clients also requested a simpler picker.

I implemented it through the theme, by adding approximately the following to the custom themes xml resource file:

```
    <style name="Theme.NoActionBar" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">

       <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/MyDialogTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MyDatePicker</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Holo.DatePicker">
        <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
    </style>
```